# Does Urbancode Deploy have the ability to share properties across applications?

Tags: urbancode

Some other deployment platforms such as Octopus Deploy have the concept of shared variables/properties/values across applications. For instance, there may be 25 applications that all consume an API at a configurable URL. In the case that the URL changes, it would be ideal to change that value in one place.

Is there anything in UCD that supports that type of arrangement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While System level variables are global, the Resource tree variables are likely what you want. The Resource tree is a hierarchical, cascading set of variables that can be overridden at lower branches, but inherit from parent branches.

- At the root level, create folder (Resource Group) for each Application
- Under the Application folder, create folder for each
  Environment in the Application
- Under the Environment folder, add the Agents (target machines)
- Under the Agents, map the corresponding    Components Add additional
  folders as needed or desired

[image: Standard resource tree pattern]
Here is the documentation on resources:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_7.1.1/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/getstart_resource_create.html

Answer (score 3):

You can set a "system" level variable for this under "Settings"->"Properties" in the top bar. These properties can be referenced with the syntax `${p:system/property-name}` and are accessible across all applications.